Unreal Engine 5 doesn't work correctly with ubuntu 23.10
I am new at ubuntu & unreal engine (both, I know). I installed Unreal Engine 5.3.2 following some youtube video. It seems that unreal engine has been installed but I can't seem to see the usual .exe file to run it. Instead if I go to /home/xyz/Documents/unrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux and run a file called 'unrealEditor' then unreal engine starts and I am able to use it as intended, but this seems like a backward entry to run unreal engine. Am I missing something? I have attached a snapshot of this file.


That seems like a silly place to install UnrealEditor, ~/bin or /usr/local/bin is more traditional, read man hier.
You can add /home/xyz/Documents/unrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux to your PATH by adding:
export PATH="$PATH:/home/xyz/Documents/unrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux"

to your ~/.bashrc file. Then, after you source ~/.bashrc or logout/login, you can type UnrealEditor to invoke it.
Or, you could use an alias, adding to ~/.bashrc:
alias ue="/home/xyz/Documents/unrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/UnrealEditor"

Then, use ue to run it.
